# Driver services windows web server 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, drivers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drivers initialization after reboot](https://serverfault.com/questions/462305/drivers-initialization-after-reboot)

I have a remote server with Windows Web Server 2008 SP2.

It seems that video/audio drivers wont install even with the correct version of drivers.

According to AIDA64 The motherboard is Intel DN2800MT. i have downloaded the latest graphics drivers but it wont install and just display the yellow sign on it in device manager.

The biggest problem is the audio, the audio is disabled in the bios but i have installed A VSC (virtual sound card drivers) from e2esoft. they worked on the same machine with server 2012 but just wont work for 2008, the driver is installed and no errors are appearing, but the device is not listed in the sound settings, just like if there is no driver installed.

- The windows audio services is on automatic and started
- the CoRD app (the app i am remotely connecting with) is set to allow the remote system audio

All of this leads me to believe that it involves a drivers related system service or something that is not installed in the web server..

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any sort of driver-related service that I know of. If there was an error preventing you from installing drivers, your install would probably be fundamentally screwed in a bad way. Make sure you're up-to-date with Windows Updates, as I've seen some new driver framework-related updates recently.

Go to the device manager and get the Hardware ID string for the missing devices and Google for it. It's possible that you downloaded the drivers for the wrong model, or downloaded x86 instead of x64 drivers, or vice versa.

Also, try installing the drivers manually for each device in the device manager by selecting the INF from the extracted driver download.