# Drivers initialization after reboot

Tags: windows, installation, drivers, windows-server-2012

For some reason. any driver i'm installing customary, like Virtual Sound Card drivers, do not initialize after reboot.

I tried virtual sound card drivers, they initialize fine when installing, but after reboot i cant see the device in sound devices. (the plugin is listed in device manager though)

I tried the following:

[Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm#sysreq)

Is there any settings i need to know that is related to saving such configurations for a user before a restart?

Im using Windows Server 2012.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and mark it accepted when you are able.  This will help others when searching for issues like this.

Comment: i tried but i have 8 points which forbids me..if you could vote up i might be able to :)

Comment: Weird -- [The privileges table](http://serverfault.com/privileges/create-posts) indicates you should only need 1 rep to post a question or answer.  In addition, I see that you answered, then deleted, [on your other question](http://serverfault.com/questions/461455/driver-services-windows-web-server-2008).

Comment: yup, i posted in the wrong question lol..thank you..answer posted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that those drivers didn't have a digital signature and needed to be signed manually..in a way.

This guide was very helpfull for those who stumble upon this problem:

http://www.justinscustomcomputers.com/vent.html